# Advice on Real Estate Database for Comparative Analysis in Berlin

Tags: data-request, data.gov, database, germany, real-estate

I am currently working on my thesis, which involves conducting a comparative analysis of machine learning methods for predicting the sale velocities in the real estate industry of Berlin. To achieve this, I need a database containing information about Berlin's real estate properties from the past few years, including various characteristics, listing dates, and sale dates.

I am not looking for just a few examples but rather hundreds, if not thousands, of entries. Since I have some knowledge of web scraping, I could also take the informations directly from a website but I'm unsure about which website would provide historical data on real estate transactions in Berlin. Many platforms focus on current listings rather than past sales.

Do any of you have suggestions on where I might find such a database or which websites could be valuable for web scraping historical real estate data in Berlin? Any advice or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!